# GsonBigQueryInputFormat saves ints as strings

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I have been using the Google Bigquery Hadoop Connector and it seems when trying to save the output of a table to json, the resulting json has fields which are actually numbers (Ints or Longs) converted to strings.

For example, if my table in Bigquery has one column "foo" of type "Integer" the output json would be

```
{"foo":"1234"}
```

This basically makes any json parser read that field has a string instead of int.

I am saving the file using:

```
.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        hadoopConf,
        classOf[GsonBigQueryInputFormat],
        classOf[LongWritable],
        classOf[JsonObject])
```

Any help would really be appreciated on this, I've been stuck on it for days!

[Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3777211/dennis-huo) since your a contributor on the project, perhaps you can help

Comment: I think this is because JSON doesn't have integer type, only number type implemented as floating point, so translating BQ integer to JSON number would lose precision. Translating it to string doesn't lose precision, but requires application to translate back to integer.

Comment: Thanks @MoshaPasumansky so I have to implement a method that takes in a generic JSON string and translate it to integer/double/float?

Comment: Yes, although this method will only work if your integers are small enough to fir into JSON number without losing precision.

Comment: Hmm so what is the best data type to use in Scala? Double? Float?

Comment: Can't you use just call 'toLong();` on the strings? The integer values returned by BigQuery should fit in the range of Scala's `long` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of what Mosha mentioned in the comments regarding JSON not having an integer type, in your case you probably want to try using the [AvroBigQueryInputFormat](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/AvroBigQueryInputFormat.java) instead. Avro will support the right numeric types. The only changes would be:

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData
import com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.AvroBigQueryInputFormat
...

// Load data from BigQuery.
val tableData = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    conf,
    classOf[AvroBigQueryInputFormat],
    classOf[LongWritable],
    classOf[GenericData.Record]).cache
```

Comment: I think this answer should resolve my issue but facing the Error : object not serializable (class: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record